# Remove numeric number 1 after application name from Google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have upload my android android application to Google Play.That application is already uploaded but I have not keystore and email ID so that I can not update or delete the application.Then I have changed the packages name and upload application on Google market.But some problem are coming that by default in application name lastly add 1.I am not understand from where 1 is coming.Please suggest me hoe to remove numerical 1 after application name from Google play store

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you mean? Maybe a screenshot of this issue in the play store?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title of your application from the [Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2/). Does it look correct there but incorrect on the play store?